Plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'] was not found
I am building an android application and I have not one but two problems here.
When I run my code I am getting this error.
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\StudioProjects\twinflameschool\android\app\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

Even though I have upgraded by Gradle files according to new norms of the flutter group as mentioned in this link:  https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
I am getting this warning:
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply

Full error is here:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
You are applying Flutter's app_plugin_loader Gradle plugin imperatively using the apply script method, which is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Migrate to applying Gradle plugins with the declarative plugins block: https://flutter.dev/to/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\StudioProjects\twinflameschool\android\app\build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I'll be grateful for your help in solving this problem.

could you attach your build.gradle file
